# How often a single news is shown

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I'm using TYPO3 7.6 and the extension news from Georg Ringer. I'm looking for a way to count, how often a news is shown in the singleview? And I want to output this value in the news singleview.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this. Easiest way would be to use an external website counter for every news. A better way would be to add a field in the news table, extend the news controller and counter this field up every time the singleView is called.

Comment: extending the controller for that should not be done as that means that the caching must be disabled which would be bad for performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion there are 2 possible ways which would still care about performance and let the detail view cacheable.

1.) If you use Google Analytics, Piwik, ... use its API to get the correct counts from there and put it back. This could be done by a scheduler task which runs every x hours/minutes

2.) Use a tracking pixel. Insert a tracking pixel which is connected to a php script (for further reading, google for **eID**) which will be called with every hit. Then you just need to write it back.

---

IMO there is no extension for neither of those 2 solutions available in public. However I did something similar as solution #2 which can be found at https://github.com/georgringer/newsmostread

Comment: How should i contact you?

Comment: I know that one :D The Ext does exactly what you need.

Comment: not at all, it counts IP hits, but i need sessions.